# Override a method in a mock object

Tags: scala, unit-testing

I need to write a unit test in which one of the dependencies of the tested object will be mocked. In that mocked object I would like to override one function (I do not care about the other functions at all).

What I need to do, is to provide a completely new implementation of that function. I am not particularly happy with providing mockito-style `when / thenResult` pairs for each potential input, i.e. I do not want to write:

```
when(mock.foo(5)).thenResult(3)
when(mock.foo(7)).thenResult(121)
...
```

I would rather like to write something like:

```
mock.foo = (a: Int) => if (a == 5) 3 else ...
```

Which mocking framework should I choose to substitute the whole implementation of a function in an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a mocking framework at all if you're only overriding one method and want to do it by actually defining the method.

If it's a class, just extend your class, override the method and inject your extension.

If it's an object or a final class of course you can't extend, but then you wouldn't be able to mock with many frameworks either, or inject an alternate easily.

Comment: I thought about this, but this would mean invoking the constructor of the "mocked" object. In some cases I would like to avoid this (e.g. when I'm mocking database access classes that may have some database-related initialization in the constructor)

Comment: You could override the constructor as well so it doesn't do the database stuff.  But if things get too messy, you should indeed use a mock and probably live with the when-then stuff.

Answer (score 0):

http://scalamock.org/user-guide/advanced_topics/

See "onCall" method

(fooMock.increment _) expects(*) onCall { arg: Int => arg + 1}